# A polite form of "bitching about something"

Tags: phrase-request, informal-language, alternatives

I'm looking for a phrase that would get along the full meaning (complaining about something, swearing at it, talking just out of the need to vent) but wouldn't sound as inappropriate.

Comment: How about "grumble"?

Answer (score 2):

**Grumble**, as suggested by @DialFrost, is a good choice.

So are **moan** and **whinge**.

And perhaps, in certain contexts, also:

**kick up** (or **make**) **a fuss about** something

Answer (score 1):

One popular idiom is to say that someone "vented his/her frustrations at [x]".

It really captures the idea that frustration had built up like pressure and was then released. It is then left to the imagination as to how they displayed that frustration - swearing, shouting etc.